# Node.JS Multipart upload to facebook graph

Tags: http, node.js, https, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload a photo to facebook and I can't find seem to get the `multipart` upload working. I can't find any documentation or libraries that do this. Has anyone else had any luck with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [restler](https://github.com/danwrong/restler) library for this instead. I've used it for this exact purpose, and it works great.

Here is some modified code from their examples to show how a file POST would go.

```
// multipart request sending a file and using https
rest.post('https://twaud.io/api/v1/upload.json', {
  multipart: true,
  data: {
    'sound[message]': 'hello from restler!',
    'sound[file]': rest.file('doug-e-fresh_the-show.mp3', null, null, null, 'audio/mpeg')
  }
}).on('complete', function(data) {
  sys.puts(data.audio_url);
});
```